# Set variable with function

Tags: javascript, externalinterface

I'm trying to use ExternalInterface to modify an HTML page, but it is only able to call Javascript functions and not set variables.  What I want to do is set a variable with a function, like doing `set_var('foo','bar')` would be equivalent to `var foo='bar'`.
In PHP, I could make a function like:

```
function set_var($varname, $value)
{
    $GLOBALS[$varname]=$value;
}
```

But I don't know how to do this in Javascript.  Maybe something with the window object?

Comment: Maybe `window[varname]=value`?  That will set the global variable `varname` to `value`.

Comment: @charlietfl - you do need the `window` part because you have a variable name in a string.  Unless you want to use `eval()`, you need an object to get to the variable with a string as the variable name.

Comment: use javascript objects i think is another way

Comment: @jfriend00  yup...wasn't reading this right

Comment: @JanTuroň : Please explain.  I don't see anything in that MDN article about `configurable: false`.  Using `window[key]` has always worked for me.  Have I been doing stuff wrong?

Comment: @JanTuroň : Thanks for the explanation.  I will watch out for that in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right path with the window object for accessing global variables in javascript via a string that contains the name of the variable.

```
function set_var(varname, value) {
    window[varname] = value;
}
```

In javascript, you can use `[]` to access properties on an object.  If the name of the property is in a variable, this is the only way (other than using `eval()`) to access the property name.  Since global variables are properties on the `window` object in browser-javascript that's why this works.

Comment: Thank you!  I thought that [] could only be used for arrays!

Comment: @hidividedby5 - It can also be used for accessing properties on an object.

Comment: I it would be more appropriate to encourage SuperScript to promote his comment into answer instead of hijacking his comment two minutes after his post...

Comment: @JanTuroň - I didn't see what SuperScript wrote.  I took the PHP that the OP had and put it into javascript.

Comment: This [was discussed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207638/comment-promoted-to-answer) and the overall view was that all of this was fine. Answers are answers, if there is no existing answer then adding a correct one is a good thing (whether you saw the comment or not)